# Parse subscript in markdown with react-markdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-markdown

I wrote this syntax to get subscript in an .md file:

```
   x_i
   x~i~
```

*react-markdown* did not parse this as a subscript. I found the package [remark-sub-super](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-sub-super) and this plugin as follows:

```
       <ReactMarkdown
          renderers={customRenderers }
          plugins={[remarkSubSuper]}
        >
          {blog.content}
        </ReactMarkdown>
```

This gives me an error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'sub_super' of undefined`.
I also added `skipHtml=true` to the component and wrote this in the *.md* file:

```
  b<sub>i</sub>
```

This did not work either. I am using *next.js*.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code

```
<ReactMarkdown children={props.content} 
components={{ 
      em: ({ node, ...props }) => { 
              if ( props.children[0] && typeof props.children[0] === 'string' && props.children[0].startsWith('^')) { 
                    return <sup>{props.children[0].substring(1)}</sup> 
               } 
              if ( props.children[0] && typeof props.children[0] === 'string' && props.children[0].startsWith('~')) { 
                    return <sub>{props.children[0].substring(1)}</sub> 
               } 
             return <i {...props} /> 
            },
 }}
```

Basically we are creating a new custom plugin.